# Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't seem to support sparse files

Tags: 15.10, filesystem, ext4

On Ubuntu 15.10 using ext4 when I perform

```
truncate -s 512M test.img
du -h test.img
```

the output is

```
513M    test.img
```

however if I run

```
 du -h --apparent-size test.img
```

the output is

```
512M    test.img
```

Why is apparent size smaller than actual size, and why is actual size not 0kb?

Comment: On my ext4 disk with 15.10, `du -h test.img` returns 0, while `du -h --apparent-size` returns 512. I created the file exactly as you did. Maybe you turned off sparse files in your mount options or something like that? What directory is the file located? And please add the output of `mount | grep '^/dev'` to list all mounted physical devices and their mount options.

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this on a colleague's Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box. Prompted by @Byte Commander (thanks!) I checked the mounts and saw there was some eCryptfs stuff on his home dir, which it seems is an option during the Ubuntu install wizard. Dodgy handling of sparse files appears to be a [deficiency of eCryptfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Deficiencies). Creating sparse files outside the home directory, however, worked as expected.